# Add elements to Drop down bb 10 cascades

Tags: blackberry-10

i have a Drop down in Qml file like...

```
 DropDown {

                enabled: true
                // text only
                Option {
                    text: "EUR/USD"

                }

            }
```

and my Database base read function is like...
    QList   DatabaseOperations::readRecords(QString tableName){

```
QList<QString> sym_ID_List;
  // 1. Get the local DB connection. Note, called database()
  //    Will automatically open a connection to the database
     QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::database(); // opens the default database.

  // 2. Create a query to search for the records
     QSqlQuery query(database);
     const QString sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+tableName;

     if (query.exec(sqlQuery)) {

         // Get the field indexes. We know the order of the fields, and could skip this step.
         // However this will still work if the fi changeldse order in the query string.
         const int customerIDField = query.record().indexOf("SymbolId");

         // 3. Start navigating through the records by calling the 'next' function.
        //     When there are no longer any records it will return false.
         int recordsRead = 0;
         while (query.next()) {
             // 4. Access the data (stored in the query) via the field indexes
             //    and add the data to the model.

                sym_ID_List.insert(recordsRead,query.value(1).toString());


             recordsRead++;
         }
         qDebug() << "Read " << recordsRead << " records succeeded";
         if (recordsRead == 0) {
            // alert(tr("The customer table is empty."));
         }
     } else {
        // alert(tr("Read records failed: %1").arg(query.lastError().text()));
     }

     // 6. Optionally close the database connection if we no longer plan to use it
     database.close();
     return sym_ID_List;
```

}

once...this method ie Executed, It returns all the Symbol Id's in an "Qlist". now my Question is how to Add these "Qlist" elements dynamiccaly into Drop Down?

How to achive it,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first thing you need to do is expose your QML Dropdown to C++. This is done with an object name property ala:

```
DropDown {
    objectName: "myDropDown"
    Option {
        text: "EUR/USD"
    }
}
```

Next, find this child from your C++:

```
QmlDocument *qml =  QmlDocument::create("asset:///my.qml");
Container *root = qml->createRootObject<bb::cascades::Container>(); //or whatever the root control is
DropDown *dropDown = root->findChild<DropDown*>("myDropDown");
```

Finally, add the options from a QList:

```
foreach (QString string, list) {
    dropDown->add(Option::create().text(list));
}
```